# How to aggregate every 2 rows from a table with a single string column?

Tags: pyspark

I have a table "crew" with only 1 column "name":

```
|          | Column: name |
| -------- | ------------ |
| Row 1    | Alice        |
| Row 2    | Bob          |
| Row 3    | Carol        |
| Row 4    | David        |
```

What I want to have:

```
|          | Column: names |
| -------- | ------------- |
| Row 1    | Alice, Bob    |
| Row 2    | Carol, David  |
```

Or:

```
|          | Column: names  |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Row 1    | [Alice, Bob]   |
| Row 2    | [Carol, David] |
```

Order and the way to group don't matter. For example, `Alice, Carol`, `[Alice, Carol]`, `Bob, Alice`, `[Bob, Alice]` are all good values of "names".

Is there a way to achieve this?
I tried with pyspark.sql.function.flatten, but I failed.

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the approach below, but note that it's not deterministic. It might produce different lists of names each time it runs.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

_data = [
    ('Alice', ), ('Bob', ), ('Carol', ), ('David', ),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(_data, ['name'])

grouping_col = F.monotonically_increasing_id() % F.lit(2)
df = df.withColumn('grouping_col', grouping_col)

res_df = (
    df
    .groupBy('grouping_col')
    .agg(F.collect_list('name').alias('names'))
)
res_df.show()

# +------------+--------------+
# |grouping_col|         names|
# +------------+--------------+
# |           0|[Alice, Carol]|
# |           1|  [Bob, David]|
# +------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. I got ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/zhao/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 5105, in withColumns
    assert len(colsMap) == 1
AssertionError``` when running `df = df.withColumns('grouping_col', grouping_col)` in local python3 prompt.

Comment: Sorry, edited the code